# Include Excel formula in block generated from SQL

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online, invantive-sql

Running Invantive Control for Excel, I want to fill a block with data from Exact Online. However, one of the columns should be the multiplication of the rate listed in a settings Excel worksheet with the amount in another column.

When both values are available in SQL, I can just do a multiplication. Similarly, by hand I can (after synchronization) add a column to the right of the block with Excel the formula.

But I seem unable to automatically include an Excel formula in the cells of the block.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query associated with an Invantive Control block you can include formulas in three variants:

```
select pjt.code
,      pjt.description
,      pjt.budgetedamount
,      '=2*3' formula1
,      '=b4*2' formula2
,      '=$C{D,.,.,.-1,.}*2' formula3
from   exactonlinerest..projects pjt
order
by     pjt.code
```

The column `formula1` has a static Excel formula which is evaluates to 6. The Excel formula must follow the Excel formula syntax in *English*, so use `sum()` instead of `som()`.

The column `formula2` uses a value taken from an Excel expression outside of the block, in this case from the cell B4.

The column `formula3` uses the most advanced type of formula with so-called [Cell Reference Expressions](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/invantive-control-for-excel/webhelp/invantive-control-celreferentie-werking.html). Commonly used cell reference expressions are available in the building block menu as shown in picture (Dutch):

[image: pre-defined common Cell Reference Expressions]

However, when you synchronize the model like this, `formula3` will raise an error since you need to make explicit that a value may contain a column expression. For this reason, go to the tab 'Fields' of the block and check the checkboxes in column 'Formula' and 'Replace Column Expressions':

[image: Enable use of cell reference expressions]

The result of synchronization will be something shown in picture:

[image: Result of three types of formula]